# Can't create new jupyter notebooks: Forbidden

Tags: firefox, jupyter-notebook

When I try to create a new notebook and want to rename, there is a 'forbidden' text and it does save; Sometimes I cannot even open the notebook. This only happens for Firefox, when I use Chromium it works without problems. I am working on a newly-installed ArchLinux Machine with the newest updates, i.e. firefox 61.0.1-1 and jupyter-notebook 5.3.0-3. What could be the problem?

These are the error messages I get for Firefox:

> [W 20:19:17.449 NotebookApp] Forbidden [W 20:19:17.450 NotebookApp]
>   403 GET /api/sessions?_=1531678729650 (::1) 1.│
>   http://localhost:8888/?token=af69163976a5d33cec387969564002b49b0932
>   21ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree

and

> [W 20:19:12.339 NotebookApp] Forbidden  [W 20:19:12.340 NotebookApp]
>   403 PUT /api/contents/Untitled.ipynb (::1)
>   1.1│kathinka/Documents/DSA/2018/github/Seminar_Chaos/src                       8ms
>   referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb?kernel_name=pyth│[I
>   20:22:03.856 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
>   on3